# Fuse.js ignoring given keys

Tags: node.js, typescript, fuse.js

I am trying to use fuse.js to search some data but it seems to ignore my key and search the entire item.

I parse a json file with array of data like this.  It seems to find words any where even the nest key "desc".

```
[
   {
        "name": "Kael",
        "rarity": "rare",
        "stage": "early",
        "title": "Early Game Kael Build 1",
        "author": "3030030003",
        "data": [
            {
                "label": "Masteries",
                "desc": "Some text.",
                "image": "https://linktosomeimage.com/image.jpg"
            },
            {
                "label": "Stats and equipment",
                "desc": "More text",
                "image": "https://linktosomeimage.com/image.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
{
        "name": "Other character",
        "rarity": "rare",
        "stage": "early",
        "title": "Some title",
        "author": "3030030003",
        "data": [
            {
                "label": "Masteries",
                "desc": "Some text with Kael in it.",
                "image": "https://linktosomeimage.com/image.jpg"
            },
            {
                "label": "Stats and equipment",
                "desc": "More text",
                "image": "https://linktosomeimage.com/image.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

```
const fuzzy = new Fuse(guides, {
            keys: ['name']
        });
const result = fuzzy.search('kael');
```

It returns expected data but also items that the search term in a key that I don't give, in this dumbed down example I would get both item as result.  I can give more info if it is needed.

Thanks,

Comment: I tried your example at https://fusejs.io/demo.html, and I got only first item. Is this result what you want? You would be better off trying too.

Comment: I guess my understanding of the threshold value was off.  I guess its just matching more characters than I was expecting.  I will try to fine tune my options.